# What is process JL3295.exe?

Tags: virus, process

Opened task manager this morning and saw this process JL3295.exe. Googled it - nothing. Opened process monitor and it's not visible there (but still visible in task manager). I've got AVG free edition up and running and system scan shows nothing. It's got a fairly small footprint - 0% CPU and 2,744K memory usage. 
What could it be? Is it a virus?

Comment: What is the MD5?

Comment: Processes are only visible in Process *Monitor* if they use the monitored resources. Did you mean Process *Explorer*?

Comment: @soandos - how do I get the MD5?

Comment: Right click, open file location, use any tool that can take the MD5.

Comment: @grawity - no, I meant Process Monitor. Looking at it with Process Explorer I can see it belongs to Trend Micro AV. Some people seem to think it's a virus - http://www.file.net/process/ofcdog.exe.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a virus. This may tell you for sure:

1. Open a command box.
2. Change to the root of the drive with this command: `cd\`.
3. Do a `dir JL3295.exe /s` to find out where the file is located.
4. Open up Explorer, and go find the file. Right click on it, and check the Properties>Details tab.

Between the directory it is in, and the page, you should be able to tell if it is legitimate. If it has nothing listed in the details page as to who made it, and it is located on one of your temp directories, or Internet temp directories, you probably have a virus. If it is in \Program Files, and you can Google the maker of the file, and see they are legit, you are probably OK.